# codeigniter Image View in slider

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code is as follows:

```
<?php foreach($posts_unapproved  as $user) ?>
    <?php foreach(unserialize($posts_unapproved[]->post_image) as $a){  ?>                                
    <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="<img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/".$a ?>" style="height:100px;" 
    style="width:100px;" alt="25"/>" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <?php }?><?php echo base_url()."assets/".$a?>"
    <!--  Example item end -->
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Why Multiple images Not Shown On My View page ?

Comment: it will be better to provide more details about your issue , what's the problem ? , what you are expecting to get ? and what you are actually get

Comment: Your code is not well formatted. Please format it properly so, you can get help quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your CSS and Array of images you are getting. I am rendering my view like this

```
<div class="aa-properties-details-img" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
<?php
 if(count($property[0]['images'])>0)
 {
  for($i=0;$i<count($property[0]['images']);$i++)
  {
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $property[0]['images'][$i]['image_url']?>" alt="img">
  <?php
  }
 }
 else
 {
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo base_url().'img/no-image.jpg'?>" alt="img">
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

And its in Production over [HERE](https://duperty.com/realestate/property/property_detail/18/Single-BHK-for-Rent). Please dump your $posts_unapproved array to see if you are getting images data from the model or function where you are querying your database if the data is coming from one.